# Shows a tiny black square on setting canvas height and width to img.offsetHeight and img.offsetWidth

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to display a canvas with an image drawn in it (especially to prevent downloading the image by chrome mobile users). When i am setting the `canvas.style.height` to `img.offsetHeight` and `canvas.style.width` to `img.offsetwidth` (here `img=document.getElementById("img-element")`) its just showing a small black square, as if its height and width are 0.

Here is the code:

```
window.onload=function(){  
  var c = document.getElementById("c");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("img");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1);
  c.style.height=(img.offsetHeight);
  c.style.width=(img.offsetWidth);
}
```

```
<img src="Icon.png" id="img" style="display:none">
<canvas id="c" style="border:2px solid #001100" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  lol ur potato pc doesn't support canvas!!!
</canvas>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

output:
[image]

Comment: The height and width are zero. You set the canvas to img.offsetWidth or Height which both return 0 when console logged. According to the docs if the element is hidden that will happen. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Comment: What should i do instead?

Comment: You can add 1 to the offset values to get the canvas to size properly. ` c.style.height=(img.offsetHeight+1);
  c.style.width=(img.offsetWidth+1);`

Comment: Ok i see....... but since the offsetHeight and offsetWidth return 0, shouldn't that return just 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would write it. First instead of using style on the canvas width and height just set it as c.width and c.height. I would also set those before drawing the image. Also give the image a width and height and use visibility instead of display. This means you have to set the position to absolute to remove it from the html flow.

```
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/79/mask-icons-whirl.jpg" id="img">
<canvas id="c" style="border:2px solid #001100" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  lol ur potato pc doesn't support canvas!!!
</canvas>
```

```
#img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```
window.onload=function(){
  var c = document.getElementById("c");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("img");  
  c.height = img.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  c.width = img.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1);
}
```